# Exception in Microsoft Bot Builder

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Okay I have a project that merges LUIS and QnA bots. I ran my code in the emulator and it works flawlessly. However when I remotely deployed my project, after making a few successful hits, I'm receiving this exception:

**exceptionMessage": "Operation returned an invalid status code '429'**

So I wait about a minute and I send another msg through and the bot works again.

From what I understand, this happens because I'm going through ngrok.io and it's rate limiting my requests.

The thing is that I need to tunnel through ngrok! So is there any alternative to use here, or maybe a way to configure ngrok to NOT limit my requests?

[The bot is deployed on an EC2 instance if that makes any difference]

Comment: _"maybe a way to configure ngrok to NOT limit my requests"_ - upgrade to a paid plan? The free plan allows one request every 3 seconds IIRC. But if this is just for testing, that should be enough?

Comment: Did you use `localtunnel`?

Comment: @stuartd thank you for the info about ngrok.I guess I can work with the current limit for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngrok, then it is possible that ngrok is limiting your requests.
More details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#what-causes-an-error-with-http-status-code-429-too-many-requests